# Will signing into my Sandbox account mess with my main account on my Iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

If I sign out of my main account on my iphone and sign in with my Sandbox account will it erase or mess with anything attached to my main account? I am trying to test In app purchases for my game.

Answer (score 0):

> will it erase or mess with anything attached to my main account?

**No.** That's why it's called a sandbox -- it's a safe, contained place to try things out.